# Adding a specific binary (zsh) to the $PATH?

Tags: macos, command-line, zsh, homebrew

I have installed a more recent version of **zsh** using **homebrew**, located at `/usr/local/bin/zsh`.

`which zsh` returns `/bin/zsh`.

How can I make `/usr/local/bin/zsh` the default, without adding the entire `/usr/local/bin` directory to the beginning of my `$PATH`?

Comment: Ugly but working:

Add ~/bin to your path *before* the /bin entry. Then create a [soft] link to /usr/local/bin/zsh

Comment: why not add `/usr/local/bin` to the beginning of `$PATH`?

Comment: @MattDMo because I don't want everything in there to be used as default.

Answer (score 2):

Just symlink it to /usr/bin or some other folder before /bin:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/zsh /usr/bin/
```

If you want to change the login shell, add /usr/local/bin/zsh to /etc/shells and run chsh.

I have /usr/local/bin before /bin on the path, and I haven't really run into any issues because of it. Some TextMate commands don't work with newer versions of Ruby or bash though.

Comment: TextMate uses its own path that can be configured in case of problems

Comment: Yeah, but I also wanted to make `#!/usr/bin/env bash` bash 4.